# Image does not load in external WebBrowser (Firefox)

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have created dynamic webproject and i am using following code to upload the image and retrieve from the same location.now when i am trying to run the application in external browser it shows rectangle box instead of image.getting loaded in external web browser gives an error.

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.sql.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.*;

public class UploadImage extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        System.out.println("request: " + request);
        if (!isMultipart) {
            System.out.println("File Not Uploaded");
        } else {
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            List items = null;

    try 
    {
          items = upload.parseRequest(request);
          System.out.println("items: " + items);
    } 
   catch (FileUploadException e) 
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
        Iterator itr = items.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
        FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
        if (item.isFormField())
            {
              String name = item.getFieldName();
              System.out.println("name: " + name);
              String value = item.getString();
              System.out.println("value: " + value);
        }
           else
           {
            try 
                 {
             String itemName = item.getName();
             Random generator = new Random();
             int r = Math.abs(generator.nextInt());
                 String reg = "[.*]";
             String replacingtext = "";
             System.out.println("Text before replacing is:-"+ itemName);
             Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(reg);
             Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(itemName);
             StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                 while (matcher.find())
                 {
             matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, replacingtext);
             }
             int IndexOf = itemName.indexOf(".");
             String domainName = itemName.substring(IndexOf);
             System.out.println("domainName: " + domainName);
                 String finalimage = buffer.toString() + "_" + r+ domainName;
             System.out.println("Final Image===" + finalimage);
        File savedFile = new File("D:\\test1\\" + "images\\"+ finalimage);
             item.write(savedFile);
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<table><tr><td>");
            out.println("<img src=D:\\test1\\images\\" + finalimage+ ">");
        out.println("</td></tr></table>");
            Connection conn = null;
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/erp";
            String username = "system";
            String userPassword = "manager";
        String strQuery = null;
        try 
            {
        System.out.println("itemName::::: " + itemName);
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,userPassword);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        strQuery = "insert into testimage values('"+ finalimage + "')";
            int rs = st.executeUpdate(strQuery);
        System.out.println("Query Executed Successfully++++++++++++++");
            out.println("image inserted successfully");
        out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
            finally
            {
        conn.close();
        }
        } 
           catch (Exception e)
           {
        e.printStackTrace();
            }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting an `src` attribute that references a local file: `D:\\...`. Of course an "external" client will know nothing about that .

Comment: so how to give a path to D drive so browser is able to load the image?

Comment: That's the problem. You should **not** use a local path. You should save the image somewhere in the server, and provide a GET endpoint therein that will return the image when requested. The `src` attribute should be the URL of this endpoint.

Comment: i have created a images folder in web content directory and save all the images in that folder but that does not work.still getting the rectangle box                                           out.println("<img src=C:\\workplace\\project1\\WebContent\\images" + finalimage">");

Answer (score 1):

The process is roughly as follows:

- Enduser requests a web page on a certain URL.
- Webbrowser sends HTTP request to webserver on the given URL.
- Webserver retrieves HTTP request and returns the desired web page as HTTP response.
- Webbrowser retrieves HTTP response in flavor of HTML code.
- Webbrowser parses HTML code in order to present it and encounters an `<img>` element.
- Webbrowser attempts to download the image from the location as specified in its `src` attribute.

And there is where it fails. You specified a fixed local disk file system path which is only valid if the webbrowser runs at **physically the same machine** as the webserver (as would occur in development environment, but absolutely not in production environment). You can't and shouldn't expect that the enduser has the desired image at exactly the given location of his local disk file system. Even more, you can't and shouldn't expect that the enduser has a `D:` disk, let alone that the enduser is also running Windows.

You should instead be specifying a fullworthy URL in image's `src` attribute. Exactly the one as you would enter in webbrowser's address bar in order to see the image, starting with a `http://` or `https://` scheme.

There are several ways to achieve this, the two most popular ways are:

1. Expose the upload folder as a virtual host. This is to be done in server config. You didn't tell which one you're using, but let's assume that it's Tomcat like as many starters would use: open `/conf/server.xml` file and add the following element to the `<Host>` element:

   ```xml
   <Context docBase="D:\test1\images" path="/images" />
   ```

   The `docBase` specifies the root folder where all files reside and the `path` specifies the context path which you would see after the domain part in the URL. This way the images will be accessible through `http://example.com/images/...`.

   ```java
   out.println("<img src=\"/images/" + finalimage+ "\">");
   ```

   ---
2. Create a simple servlet which reads the image from disk and writes it to the response after having set the desired response headers telling the browser about the file content type, length and disposition so that the browser knows how to deal with it:

   ```java
   @WebServlet("/images/*")
   public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
           String filename = URLDecoder.decode(request.getPathInfo(), "UTF-8");
           File file = new File("D:\\test1\\images", filename);
           response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
           response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
           response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
           Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
       }

   }
   ```

   Also this way the images will be accessible through `http://example.com/images/...`.

   ```java
   out.println("<img src=\"/images/" + finalimage+ "\">");
   ```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, emitting HTML in a servlet is a very poor practice. You should use JSP for that. See also the *Coding style and recommendations* section of [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Have you further also thought about uploaded images which happen to have the same file name as an existing uploaded image?

Comment: +1 for reminding the very basic that `Response` object is generated inside the server, ergo resources will be searched & found accordingly.